# Nav bar owerflow problem with div boxes in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Welcome. I have a div based nav bar problem. In my case the nav bar gets overflown by other div content.
I dont now how to add properly nav bar for this page because the whole page is full of the same div box and i relly need to all of this boxes can "flex", because i want to use on a mobile phone as well. This willbe a home automatization server web page for my friend.
I hope some body can help.

```css
body {
            background-color: #111;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .page {
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .container {
            width: 95%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(400px, 1fr));
            grid-gap: 20px;
        }

        .box {
            color: white;
            border: 2px solid #696969;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #737373 0%, #333333 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #737373 0%, #333333 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, #737373 0%, #333333 100%);
            border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .headertop {
            height: 40px;
            color: white;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #696969;
            border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            border-top-right-radius: 8px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008000 0%, #00FF00 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008000 0%, #00FF00 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, #008000 0%, #00FF00 100%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .header {
            height: 40px;
            color: white;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #696969;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008000 0%, #00FF00 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008000 0%, #00FF00 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, #008000 0%, #00FF00 100%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .content {
            border: 0px solid #696969;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        }

        .largetext {
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        .boxtext {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
            margin-top: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        .boximage {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
        }

        .boxbutton {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #333333;
        }

        .headertext {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-left: 6px;
        }

        .flex-parent {
            display: flex;
        }

        .jc-center {
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .icon {
            position: center;
            margin: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 85%;
            height: 120px;
        }

        .border {
            border: 2px solid #001a34;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }

        .button {
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 1em 1em;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            display: inline-block;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 12px;
            width: 90%;
            height: 90px;
            border: 2px solid #800000;
        }

            .button:hover {
                background-color: #8B0000;
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .button:active {
                background-color: #8B0000;
                box-shadow: 0 6px#800000;
                transform: translateY(4px);
                color: #ffffff;
            }

        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
            top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
        }

            /* Links inside the navbar */
            .navbar a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                /* Change background on mouse-over */
                .navbar a:hover {
                    background: #ddd;
                    color: black;
                }

        /* Main content */
        .main {
            margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="headertop"><h2 class="headertext">Hálószoba</h2></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="boximage flex-parent jc-center">
                    <img src="C:\Users\patak\Desktop\Aktuális\Arduino_web_server_atmega2560\Visual studio web pages\centigrade.png" class="icon">
                </div>
                <div class="boxtext">
                    <a class="boxtext">Hömérséklet:</a>
                    <a class="largetext">30&deg;C</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header"><h2 class="headertext">Világítás</h2></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="boxbutton flex-parent  jc-center">
                    <button class="button" type="button">OFF</button>
                </div>
                <div class="boxbutton flex-parent jc-center">
                    <button class="button" type="button">OFF</button>
                </div>
                <div class="boximage flex-parent  jc-center">
                    <img src="https://i1.wp.com/fremontgurdwara.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/no-image-icon-2.png" class="icon border">
                </div>
                <div class="boximage flex-parent  jc-center">
                    <img src="https://i1.wp.com/fremontgurdwara.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/no-image-icon-2.png" class="icon border">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header"><h2 class="headertext">Foglalatok</h2></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="boxbutton flex-parent  jc-center">
                    <button class="button" type="button">OFF</button>
                </div>
                <div class="boxbutton flex-parent jc-center">
                    <button class="button" type="button">OFF</button>
                </div>
                <div class="boximage flex-parent  jc-center">
                    <img src="https://i1.wp.com/fremontgurdwara.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/no-image-icon-2.png" class="icon border">
                </div>
                <div class="boximage flex-parent  jc-center">
                    <img src="https://i1.wp.com/fremontgurdwara.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/no-image-icon-2.png" class="icon border">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add z-index: 999; to the navbar. The following code should look like this:

```
 .navbar {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   z-index: 999; /* Add the z-index !!! */
}
```

Comment: If you click on the tick next to the votes, you can show people who have exactly the same problem that they can solve the problem this way.